# Fancybox is not working (open in the new tab, not a popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have a problem with fancybox plugin. When i click on thumbnail image, it open the larger image in new tab (not a fancybox).

Here's my code:

```
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

I want to add fancybox here:

```
 <div id="slide">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="bigImages/cover-mockup.jpg"><img src="images/001.png" alt="" /></a>
                <div id="name4">Lettuce Eat's Flyer</div>
            </li>
```

and the fancybox script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

I've create the simple html with fancybox and it's working. I do the same on this but something wrong, i dont know... Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems you have a js error somewhere in your page that makes fancybox (and most probably other stuff) not working properly. Check for errors in your console. check you are not loading more than a single version of jQuery (some other plugins may come with a version of jQuery in their download). Start removing other scripts until you find the source of the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I've included jQuery library twice. It's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the $ with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```